# Problem with a mysql query (like) and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

i'm trying to use the statement like of sql but unfortunately I get an error every time I use the query. In a php file I have:

```
$b = "SELECT Nombre, Link, Img_Pre, Precio, Descripcion, ID, Categoria, Subcategoria 
    FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE \"%$a%\"";
```

but i get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"%THE VALUE OF A%\"' at line 1

If i try the same statement on phpmyadmin i don't have any error. Why with php I get this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using phpmyadmin's 'create PHP code' feature? Sometimes I find that can help with little syntax errors you might otherwise not find. Just copy/paste the code it created in place of your quoted code.

Comment: That's some mistype or whatever of the kind. there shouldn't be any errors, unless you're doing something unusual. there shouldn't be any \ symbols in the query. Something adding it, Doublecheck yourself. It's not PHP not mysql error, but just your mistake

Comment: what is the code between this line and query execution?

Comment: Can you provide us the $a value, try "LIKE \"%\$a\%\"";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes in your `LIKE` string instead (I believe phpMyAdmin magically converts that to single quotes for you before running the query):

```
$b = "SELECT Nombre, Link, Img_Pre, Precio, Descripcion, ID, Categoria, Subcategoria FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$a%'";
```

Make sure you've escaped `$a` using `mysql_real_escape_string()` too, because it might be breaking your queries by introducing unescaped quotes!

Comment: double quotes under php are used for Literal chars, so `"hey $username"` would convert username into its value, but `'hey $username'` would not.. it would literally print out `$username`. I believe that this is the same with mysql, there a separation of string containers to make it easy for the user to specify what to be parsed, such as escape chars etc.

Comment: @RobertPitt you are wrong. there is nothing nearly similar in mysql. Both quotes are equal in every way.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I don't know, PHP's MySQL extension just acts that way.

Comment: BoltClock nope, MySQL extension acts ether way. should of consulted the docs first as that dude just said.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$b = "SELECT Nombre, Link, Img_Pre, Precio, Descripcion, ID, Categoria, Subcategoria FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$a%'";
```

Some SQL queries will croak if you don't use apostrophes as the string delimeter

Comment: What queries? Got an example?

Comment: @Col Depends entirely on the whether you've got ANSI_QUOTES set: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Answer (score -1):

```
$b = "SELECT Nombre, Link, Img_Pre, Precio, Descripcion, ID, Categoria, Subcategoria 
    FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE \"%"+$a+"%\"";
```